# Html Pattern Attribute Match or Allow Blank

Tags: html, regex, forms

I have two input fields in html; phone_number and alt_phone_number. I want alt_phone_number to have the same pattern as phone_number with the additional option of it being blank. Any advice?

```
<input id="phone_number" maxlength="10" name="phone_number" pattern="[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{10}" placeholder="Phone Number" required="required" size="10" type="tel" />

<input id="alt_phone_number" maxlength="10" name="alt_phone_number" pattern="[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{10}" placeholder="Phone Number" required="required" size="10" type="tel" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "required" attribute from alt_phone_number.

```
<input id="alt_phone_number" maxlength="10" name="alt_phone_number" pattern="[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{10}" placeholder="Phone Number"size="10" type="tel" />
```

Comment: But if they do choose to enter an alternate phone number I want it to match a pattern before being submitted.